# "most common" typedef for basic types in C

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I had a small discussion at my work since they decided to go for a new naming convention for basic typedefs for C.

Their argument was to follow the common naming convention used by all C developers. Now, I don't really care for this change, but I do was wondering is there even such a thing? 'most common naming convention among C programmers'. I know windows tends to use naming like `WORD` and `DWORD` etc.

They decided to go from:

- `U8BIT` to `uint8_t`
- `S8BIT` to `int8_t`
- etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, there's no real naming convention, eventually you can rely on the libc style (using _t suffix, only use uppercase for macro … )

For you're example, I don't know how decision was made, but such types already exists in C99 standard header **stdint.h**: signed type have the form intS_t where S is replaced by the size in bits and unsigned types have the form uintS_t (with S … )

So, uint8_t exists in the standard and the signed version is ,int8_t (and not sint8_t.) Redefining them is a waste of time, you should prefer the provided standard.

Using provided definition has other advantages: you don't have to worry about how to correctly define sizes (remember, a lot of integer types don't have the same size across various architecture and OSes, some may even have a different signedness !)

Comment: I have to excuse me for that mistake, they indeed used the `intS_t` and `uintS_t` convention, I don't know why I wrote that wrong in the OP.

Comment: also, I noticed the boolean type has no `_t` in `stdbool.h`, so much for consistency. -_-'

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on "Windows standards" since I'm not using them.

`uint8_t` and friends is defined in stdint.h and as such kind of a "common standard".
This should not be overused in my opinion, however.

In my opinion, you should use `uint`n`_t` only in those cases where you *need* a type with a certain bit length. For all other cases, you really should leave the decision on bit length to the compiler and stay with `long`, `int` and `short`. It might very well be the case that what's good for one machine/architecture performance-wise might be disastrous for another.

Comment: Using `int` or `unsigned` is fine as a fast, general purpose type. But there is really no use for `long` or `short`. If there are restrictions that `int` cannot fulfill, using stdint.h types is better as they are more strictly defined than `short` or `long`.

Comment: @mfro: "only in those cases where you need a type". When do you *not* need a specific type? Everytime you´re using a variable, you have some conditions to it. Like "can hold array lengths" or "can count from 0 to 1000000". There are not as many use cases as one could expect for "int".

Comment: @deviantfan: I'd use an uint8_t if I had certain width requirements. E.g. to write to an 8 bit wide hardware register on an embedded controller where the next 8 bit register adress has a completely different meaning.
If I don't need that, I'd rather use a char variable.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen single character plus size (ie. u8, s8) and the more convention your workplace has decided to go with. Personally, I prefer the latter, despite requiring more typing. I would even go one further and add additional to hint the compiler what I really want.

For example, if I want an unsigned integer which is at minimum 32-bits wide, but I want it to be the fastest native type, uint_fast32_t. This is one of the advantages of the fixed width integer types in C++11 (ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). I would recommend following standard conventions wherever applicable.